# linux - insert numbered list of files into middle of another list of numbered files

Tags: linux

I have a folder (apple) containing files

```
doc001.jpg
doc002.jpg
...
doc010.jpg,
```

Another folder (banana) also contains files

```
doc001.jpg   
...
doc150.jpg
```

How can I insert the contents of apple into banana in the middle while renaming them?  So that the banana folder has it's existing files up to `doc050.jpg` then

```
apple/doc001.jpg
```

becomes

```
banana/doc051.jpg
```

and onward, and the previous `banana/doc051.jpg` through `banana/doc150.jpg` get renamed `banana/doc060.jpg` through `banana/doc160.jpg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the most elegant of solutions but it's easy to understand and should work:

1. Make a new banana folder

   ```
   mkdir banana.new
   ```
2. Copy the 1st 50 files over (this is slightly harder than it need be because of the leading `0`s):

   ```
   for i in {1..9}; do cp banana/doc00$i.jpg banana.new/; done
   for i in {10..50}; do cp banana/doc0$i.jpg banana.new/; done
   ```
3. Get apple's files and rename them

   ```
   i=51; find apple/ -type f | sort | \
     while read n; do cp $n banana.new/doc0$i.jpg; let i++; done
   ```
4. Get the rest of banana's files and rename them

   ```
   for i in {51..89}; do \
     let n=$i+10; cp banana/doc0$i.jpg banana.new/doc0$n.jpg; done
   for i in {90..99}; do \
    let n=$i+10; echo "cp banana/doc0$i.jpg banana.new/doc$n.jpg"; done
   for i in {100..150}; do \
    let n=$i+10; cp banana/doc$i.jpg banana.new/doc$n.jpg; done
   ```

At this point, `banana.new` should be exactly as you want it. **Make sure that it is** and then rename it to `banana`.